# Python Issues with a Class

Tags: python, class, instance

I am having issues with my below class. I keep getting the below traceback, butI am not sure were I am going wrong. I am expecting to see a dictionary with photo tags. Any help would be great.

Traceback:

```
File "project.py", line 231, in <module>
    new_photo = Photo(result_get_photo_data)
  File "project.py", line 228, in __init__
    for diction in photo_diction["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not st
```

My Code:

```
class Photo(object): 
    def __init__(self,photo_diction):
        self.tags = []
        for diction in photo_diction["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
            return self.tags.append(diction)

new_photo = Photo(result_get_photo_data)
print new_photo.tags
```

Some Contents of Photo Diction, its a list that contains several dictionaries.

```
[  
   {  
      u'photo':{  
         u'people':{  
            u'haspeople':0
         },
         u'dateuploaded':u'1492780609',
         u'owner':{  
            u'username':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
            u'realname':u'',
            u'nsid':u'59600577@N07',
            u'iconserver':u'2943',
            u'location':u'Bangkok,
            Thailand',
            u'path_alias':u'patrick_foto',
            u'iconfarm':3
         },
         u'publiceditability':{  
            u'canaddmeta':0,
            u'cancomment':1
         },
         u'id':u'33334692904',
         u'title':{  
            u'_content':u'Kuala Lumpur skyline'
         },
         u'media':u'photo',
         u'tags':{  
            u'tag':[  
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'aerialview',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Aerial View',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-8319'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'buildingexterior',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Building Exterior',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1727027'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'businessfinanceandindustry',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Business Finance and Industry',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-263370815'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'capitalcities',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Capital Cities',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-711565'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'citylife',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'City Life',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-7631'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'cloudsky',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Cloud - Sky',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-834640'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'colorimage',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Color Image',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-872992'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'downtowndistrict',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Downtown District',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-5634066'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'futuristic',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Futuristic',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-61798'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'nopeople',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'No People',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-9003'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'photography',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Photography',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1935'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'traveldestinations',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Travel Destinations',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-872991'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'urbanskyline',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'Urban Skyline',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-153762'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'architecture',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'architecture',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1174'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'business',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'business',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-11698'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'city',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'city',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-103'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'cityscape',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'cityscape',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-3643'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'day',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'day',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-3511'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'growth',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'growth',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-12192'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'horizontal',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'horizontal',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1049'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'kualalumpur',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'kuala lumpur',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-24092'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'malaysia',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'malaysia',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-15385'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'modern',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'modern',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1180'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'outdoors',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'outdoors',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1860'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'panoramic',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'panoramic',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-9696'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'sky',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'sky',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-282'
               },
               {  
                  u'machine_tag':False,
                  u'_content':u'skyscraper',
                  u'author':u'59600577@N07',
                  u'raw':u'skyscraper',
                  u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
                  u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1306'
               },
```

Comment: where is your traceback?

Comment: @latsha I just edited my post to include it! thanks!

Comment: The issue is not related to your class. You need to show the structure of `photo_diction`, somewhere in there you have a list stored against a key. My guess is `photo_diction["photo"]["tags"][0]["tag"]` would be valid to access the first tag, since "tags" is plural... but that's a guess since we can't see it.

Comment: you're getting list in `photo_diction` and acting like it's a dictionary

Comment: @roganjosh I just added part of the contents of photo_diction, it's rather large so I just added part of it.

Comment: You're returning from the loop

Comment: This is the problem: `photo_direction`'s a _list_, but you treat it as a dictionary.

Comment: I think you need `photo_diction[0]["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]`

Comment: @ForceBru is there a away to convert my list of dictionaries into just one large dictionary? Or is there a away that I can iterate over a list of dictionaries to extract ["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]? I can also post additional code that shows how I ended up with my list of dictionaries, but I don't want to over complicate things.

Comment: @sammie1991, why'd you do this? You could extract some value of that list and operate on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues here.

1. Your photo_dictation is a list. You need either:

   ```
   for dictation in photo_diction[0]["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
   ```

   or a double loop:

   ```
   for photo in photo_dictation:
      for dictation in photo["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]
   ```
2. you are returning within your loop. I think you probably want:

   ```
   class Photo(object): 
       def __init__(self,photo_diction):
           self.tags = []
           for diction in photo_diction["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
               self.tags.append(diction)
           return
   ```

Comment: `self.tags = list(photo_diction["photo"]["tags"]["tag"])`