# Type error when defining a class using a complex list

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to define a class that will make a list of tags from a list containing several dictionaries (see below), but when I try it out, I get the following traceback.  I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  Any advice would be appreciated!

```
  File "file.py", line 415, in <module>
    p = Photo(data)
  File "file.py", line 395, in __init__
    for d in p_d["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]["_content"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Current code:

```
class Photo :

    def __init__(self,p_d) :
        self.tags = []
        for d in p_d["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]["_content"]:
            self.tags.append(d)
        return

p = Photo(data)
print(p)
```

The contents of "data" looks like "Photo Diction" in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543917/python-issues-with-a-class).  Here's an example of the part with the tags:

```
     u'media':u'photo',
     u'tags':{  
        u'tag':[  
           {  
              u'machine_tag':False,
              u'_content':u'aerialview',
              u'author':u'59600577@N07',
              u'raw':u'Aerial View',
              u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
              u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-8319'
           },
           {  
              u'machine_tag':False,
              u'_content':u'buildingexterior',
              u'author':u'59600577@N07',
              u'raw':u'Building Exterior',
              u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
              u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-1727027'
           },
           {  
              u'machine_tag':False,
              u'_content':u'businessfinanceandindustry',
              u'author':u'59600577@N07',
              u'raw':u'Business Finance and Industry',
              u'authorname':u'Patrick Foto ;)',
              u'id':u'59579247-33334692904-263370815'
           },
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `p_d["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]` is a list, you can't take the item `['_content']` in a list.

You can do

```
for adict in p_d["photo"]["tags"]["tag"]:
    self.tags.append(adict["_content"])
```

Comment: I see that now.  If I wanted to get at just the ['_content'] bit, how should I go about it?

Comment: The problem is that each item in the list has a `'_content'`. Which one do you want? If you want only the first one, you can do `[0]['_content']`. If you want all of them, you need to add a for loop.

Comment: I'd like to return them all in a list.  Edit: Which is what I was trying to do in my current for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This makes a lot more sense!